# Fix Ubuntu reinstall

Tags: partitioning, uninstall, recovery-mode

I did something really stupid yesterday...

I accidentally did some weird command with mv and made it so the Linux filesystem could not find anything.

Anyhow, I reinstalled Ubuntu 11.10 from the same disk I did the first time, and then upgraded to 12.04 just like last time and it hasn't been the same.

- Now I have to boot into recovery mode or else I get stuck on the splash screen.
- After I log in I often have strange problems with the mouse and GUI.
- The other thing is I'm still left with pieces of the old filesystem on the last Ubuntu partition. **I think that might be interfering with the current one. *How do I delete it?***

Also, could there be other causes?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "strange problems with the mouse and GUI"?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "_I'm still left with pieces from the old filesystem_"? How do you know that? Also, why did you install 11.10 then upgrade to 12.04? Reinstalling 12.04 from scratch would be a better option.

Comment: You have an unstable system, and any of our posible solutions wouldn't work. Please, **reinstall 12.04 LTS from scratch** since it's the latest stable Long Term Support version.

Comment: Please read http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/169736 for a step-by-step guide about how to install Ubuntu.